# How to remove TTL form MongoDB collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose with node.js. I was testing Time-To-Live features and set my documents to expire after X time in the db schema:

```
var adInfos = new mongoose.Schema({                           
  inf  : { type: Object, required: false },                    
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now, expires:60 }
});
```

This seems to work right but after removing the `expires` attribute the new documents still seem to be expiring.

I have also tried setting `expires: false` and `expires:0` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose doesn't ever drop indexes, so if you change the index attributes in your schema they won't take effect until after you manually drop the existing index.

Not sure what your collection name is, but in the shell it would be something like:

```
db.adInfos.dropIndex('created_1')
```

Use `db.adInfos.getIndexes()` to see the indexes on the collection.

Comment: Thanks this seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnnyHK's answer works, and I'm adding few early steps for those who created a TTL via mongoose (where you don't control the `createdAt` name):

Connect to your db:

```
use <your db>
```

In order to know what index you need to drop, first you should get all indexes:

```
db.adInfos.getIndexes()
```

you should get something like the following:

[image]

Then you drop the index with its name:

```
db.adInfos.dropIndex("created_at_1")
```