# Mongodb schema emptied after seconds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When i am making a request to save a new object to my mongodb, it gets saved, and after seconds everything in that schema disappears.
In the screenshot below you can see this happening, where with the first command i check that the schema is empty, then i make a request to save a new object which is done successfully, and after a few seconds you can see that the object has disappeared. [image: See screenshot here]
The express endpoint looks like so:

```
router.post('/bookdate',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res) => {
const userId = req.user._id
const appartmentNumber = req.user.apartmentNumber;
const requestedDate = req.body.requestedDate;
const bookingZone = req.body.bookingZone;

const newBooking = new Booking({
    'apartmentNumber': appartmentNumber,
    'dateOfBooking': requestedDate,
    'bookingZone': bookingZone
});

if (req.user.hasTimeBooked) {
    res.json({booked: false, msg: 'There is already a booking for this user.'})
} else {
    if (typeof newBooking.requestedDate !== undefined && typeof newBooking.bookingZone !== undefined) {
        Booking.addBooking(newBooking, (err, result)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json({booked: false, msg: err})
            } else {
                res.json({booked: true, msg: result})
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.json({booked: false, msg: 'Undefined parameters Date or Zone'})
    }
}
});
```

and the mongoose schema looks like so

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../config/database');
const BookingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    apartmentNumber:{
      type: Number,
      unique: true
  },
  dateOfBooking:{
    type: Date
  },
  bookingZone:{
    type: String
  }
});  
const Booking = module.exports = mongoose.model('bookings',BookingSchema, 'bookings');

module.exports.addBooking = function(bookingObj, cb){
  var newBooking = new Booking(bookingObj);
  newBooking.save(cb);
}
```

There are no errors appearing in console, and i am not quite sure where to start looking. 
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
The result from db.bookings.getIndices() is shown in the screenshot [here](https://ibb.co/iZn23b)

Comment: Have you created any TTL indexes? Can you post `db.collection.getIndices()` output

Comment: Yes, i updated the original post.

Comment: @Saravana Thank you so much for the hint!! Following the answer from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356610/how-to-remove-ttl-form-mongodb-collection seems to have solved the issue.
Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `getIndices` output I could see you've created an TTL index on `dateOfBooking` so it gets deleted after 60 seconds in the backend

From the mongo docs [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/)

> TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to
>   automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain
>   amount of time or at a specific clock time