# Cancel TTL On Mongoose Document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a booking collection with a TTL as follows:

```
expireAt: {
 type: Date,
 required: true
}

BookingSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 })
```

This will expire at `expireAt`.
This is a booking schema that should expire when a user hasn't paid by a given date, but if they do, I'd like to prevent the document from expiring.
Couldn't find anything in the mongo docs about that though.

Maybe deleting the `expireAt` field might work? Even so it sounds a bit crude, maybe theres a more conventional way?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: Is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356610/how-to-remove-ttl-form-mongodb-collection) help?

Comment: Either, delete `expireAt`, set it to null or any other value but Date. Whatever seems less crude to you. Absence of expiration date seems most straightforward to me meaning the document doesn't expire, but if you are not comfortable with it there are options.